# Bypass terms and conditions if using omniauth and facebook

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, omniauth

I know that you can override password and email requirements by overriding the default devise methods, but when using omniauth how would you bypass having to accept the terms and conditions box I have on my signup page which uses this in my User model:

`validates :terms_of_service, acceptance: { accept: true }`

I am using devise for user authentication.

Answer (score 1):

If you have some attribute, which indicates that the user is coming from facebook (`facebook_uid` for example):

```
validates :terms_of_service, acceptance: { accept: true }, unless: facebook_uid?
```

Comment: the "uid" is blank tho b/c the user hasn't been saved to the database

Comment: if it is set in the mode, `facebook_uid?` would return true, even if it is not persisted

Comment: keep getting this with it `undefined method uid? for #<Class:0x007faf6e6403c8>`

Comment: what is the name of the attribute, that you set in the model based on the facebook id?

Comment: it is called "uid" in my db

Comment: in the users table? You can also try this: `unless: 'uid.present?'`

Comment: Worked!  Additionally I am posting another solution I found at the same time you gave me this.  I believe your answer is more idiomatically correct tho.

Answer (score 1):

Yury's answer worked fine.  At the same time I was able to arrive at this answer which also worked. User.rb file:

```
 def self.from_omniauth(auth)
    where(provider: auth.provider, uid: auth.uid).first_or_create do |user|
        user.provider = auth.provider 
        user.uid      = auth.uid
        user.name     = auth.info.name
        user.email    = auth.info.email
        user.terms_of_service = "1"
    end
  end
```

Comment: i guess this one is even more transparent